# Why 0 || 1 returns true in php?

Tags: php

In Javascript and Python, `0 || 1` returns `1`.

But in PHP, `0 || 1` returns true.

How to do if I want `0 || 1` return `1` in PHP?

another example,

`$a` is `array(array('test'))`

I want `$a['test'] || $a[0] || array()` return `array('test')`, How to do?

Comment: [Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.logical.php): `$a || $b` - `Or` - `TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The other answers appear to only care about converting boolean to an integer. I think you really want for the second value to be the result if the first is falsy (`0`, `false`, *etc.*)?

For the other languages' behaviour, the closest we have in PHP is the short-hand "ternary" operator: `0?:1`.

That could be used in your script like: `$result = get_something() ?: 'a default';`

See the [ternary operator documentation](http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) for details.

Comment: In PHP 5.3,
$a['test'] ?: $a[0] ?: array();
In PHP version < 5.3,
$b = $a['test'] or $b = $a[0] or $b = array();
then use $b.

Answer (score 9):

Because `0 || 1` is a boolean expression, it assumes you want a boolean result.

You can cast it to an int:

```
echo (int)(0 || 1);
```

Comment: echo (int) (0 || 5) will return 1 and not 5 in this case

Answer (score 3):

In PHP the operator `||` returns a boolean, either true or false.

What you probably want is something like this: `$result = (0 || 1) ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
(0 || 1) ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(0||1)
    return 1;
else return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use casting  to integer

```
echo (int)(0||1);
```

Comment: thats fails as "(int)0||1" is same as "((int)0)||1", and not "(int)(0||1)"

Answer (score 1):

Cast the result to int ;P `(int)(0 || 1)`

Although it will work only for 1. `(int)(0 || 2)` will return 1 as well.